# Checking if an index in a array in empty VB6

Tags: arrays, object, vb6

I have been getting into some object-oriented features of VB6. I've done lots of OOP with Java, and I'm trying to get this to work:

I have a array of `Card` objects, I want to check if an object in the index in the array has been created.

```
Dim cardsPlayer1(1 To 10) As Card
```

I created objects like this:

```
Set cardsPlayer1(index) = New Card
```

If tried using this to test if I have assigned an object to an index yet:

```
For counter = 1 To 10
    If (cardsPlayer1(counter) Is Nothing) Then
        Set cardsPlayer1(counter) = New Card
    End If
Next counter
```

But it gave me a true value everytime and creating a new object to the whole array.

Here's the relevant code:

```
'Jordan Mathewson
'May 31, 2013
Dim cardsPlayer1(1 To 10) As Card
Dim cardsPlayer2(1 To 10) As Card

Private Sub cmdStartGame_Click()
    Call addCard(1)
End Sub

'Called to add a card to one of the player's stacks
Private Sub addCard(player As Integer)
    Dim counter As Integer

    'To add a card to player1..
    If (player = 1) Then

        For counter = 1 To 10
            If (cardsPlayer1(counter) Is Nothing) Then
                Print "Object created." '<- Printed 10 times.
                Set cardsPlayer1(counter) = New Card
            End If
        Next counter

    'To add a card to player2..
    Else
        For counter = 1 To 10
            If (cardsPlayer2(counter) Is Nothing) Then
                Set cardsPlayer2(counter) = New Card
            End If
        Next counter

    End If

    Call refreshForm

End Sub
```

Comment: That's correct. I can't see why that wouldn't work. Is there some other part of this you're not showing? Or how do you know it's doing it wrong?

Comment: Can you copy and paste code rather than retyping? specifically the first two samples, It may help to uncover typo bugs.

Comment: An *index* can't be empty, though an *element* can be.

Comment: Alright, I'll show all the code tomorrow when I can get back to my computer.

Comment: Updated it with the actual code.

Comment: So if you call the addCard again the array is initialized again? Have you tried to put a breakpoint after and before and use watch to look what is inside? You can even ask the Watch to break when the array item becomes nothing (I am missing this feature in .net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the addCard sub should add one card but it adds all of them, when only called once. This isn't because it can't tell which array element is empty. It's just because it doesn't stop after successfully adding one.

```
For counter = 1 To 10
    If (cardsPlayer1(counter) Is Nothing) Then
        Set cardsPlayer1(counter) = New Card
        Exit For ' <-- Add this
    End If
Next counter
```

Without the `Exit For`, it will keep looping through the array and initialize the rest of it.

Comment: That's it. I cant believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might have a scoping issue. This gives me the expected results:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim objectsArray(1 To 5) As TestObject

    If objectsArray(1) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "objectsArray(1) Is Nothing"    ' <----- displayed
    End If

    Set objectsArray(1) = New TestObject

    If objectsArray(1) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "objectsArray(1) Is Nothing"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not objectsArray(1) Is Nothing"    ' <----- displayed
    End If
End Sub
```

Where do you declare objectsArray; where do you create the object; where is the loop? (Are these code snippets in different modules/class modules/functions?)